# How to click a button using Selenium, via text or value?

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to achieve clicking a HTML button via reading its Value or innerText in C# Selenium, none of the methods for click is seem to work, no idea why?

I was wondering if this is possible if so please advise my code is below.

Html below

```
<div class="a-button-stack">
<span class="a-declarative" data-action="dp-pre-atc-declarative" data-dp-pre-atc-declarative="{}" id="atc-declarative">
<span id="submit.add-to-cart-ubb" class="a-button a-spacing-small a-button-primary a-button-icon">
<span class="a-button-inner">
<i class="a-icon a-icon-cart"></i><input id="add-to-cart-button-ubb" name="submit.add-to-cart-ubb" title="Add to Shopping Basket" data-hover="Select <b>__dims__</b> from the left<br> to add to Basket" class="a-button-input" type="submit" 
value="Add to Basket" aria-labelledby="submit.add-to-cart-ubb-announce">
<span id="submit.add-to-cart-ubb-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">Add to Basket</span></span></span>
</span>

</div>
```

My code in C# is the following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Add to Basket')]")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Add to Basket')]")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'Add to Basket')]")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Add to Basket')]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//input[@value='Add to Basket']

There is no button tag but you can grab the input tag by it's data attribute value like so.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an element of a button but a button element does not exist.

The add to cart button in the html is:

```
//input[@id='add-to-cart-button-ubb']
```